# How to make Java send multiple messages together?

Tags: sockets, java

Here's an extract of my code:

```
OutputStream out = this.socket.getOutputStream();
out.write(fourBytes);
out.write(someBytes);
out.flush();
```

This gets sent in 2 packages, even though the first one is only 4 bytes long. Is there another way than concatenating the byte arrays together to send them together?

I've already tried `setTcpNoDelay(false)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. Use a `BufferedOutputStream`. :-P

The `setTcpNoDelay` changes how the OS sends packets, not how Java sends packets. The only way to change the latter is to buffer your output, as I suggested above.

BTW, this doesn't affect how many packets your data is really split up into. Again, that is up to the OS, as well as the window specified by the receiving end. So you can't use packets to delimit data.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it with buffered output stream

Answer (score 0):

I think disabling Nagle is done by `setTcpNoDelay(true)`

Comment: The OP wants to _enable_ Nagle's algorithm, not disable it. :-)

Comment: @chris Nagle algorithm means to send less number of packets by binding multiple data in one packet. So I think he needs to disable Nagle

Comment: Right, and the OP wants to join all the data into a single packet.

Comment: Hence he must set setTcpNoDelay(true) :)

Comment: @Suraj No, this is not true. Nagles algorithm is used to reduce the number of small packets by buffering outgoing packets while waiting for an ACK. So setTcpNoDelay(true) will NOT buffer them, setTcpNoDelay(false), will buffer them. Key words here are "No Delay".